# Strange Apache CustomLog behavior

Tags: docker, apache, curl, logging, health-check

I'm adding a Docker healthcheck function which I've successfully done in one container, but adding the same code to a different container is behaving strangely.

Essentially, I'm simply trying to not log certain requests, using an env var.

In `dockerfile`:

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl -ILfSs http://localhost:80 -A "HealthCheck" || exit 1

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/www/logs/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/www/logs/transfer.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/www/logs/ssl-transfer.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/www/logs/error.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/www/logs/ssl-error.log
```

In `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule setenvif_module>
       BrowserMatchNoCase ^healthcheck nolog
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access.log" combinedio env=!nolog

</IfModule>
```

So now when the healthcheck ticks, the log which would normally show this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2022:03:22:13 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "HealthCheck" 74 1095
```

shows this (it shouldn't be showing *anything at all* since the env var gets set when the UserAgent matches 'healthcheck'):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2022:05:17:46 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It acts almost as if it's doing a *replace* of everything that matches 'healthcheck' and after, with nothing at all (empty string), which I don't think it's even supposed to be capable of doing(?).

I've tested to make sure that the only healthcheck being called is this one in httpd.conf by commenting out the `BrowserMatchNoCase ^healthcheck nolog` line, and it indeed then just shows the usual, expected line containing the "HealthCheck" useragent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved; there was a "hidden" `TransferLog` in the configs duking it out with my `CustomLog`, so my stuff was actually working as intended, but the `TransferLog` was also being called, so they were both outputting to the log at the same time for each `HealthCheck` call.

I say "hidden" because even though it was there in plain sight, it was the first time I've personally encountered the `TransferLog` directive; I've always just used `CustomLog`, and wasn't aware how `TransferLog` worked in combination with `CustomLog` when they're both present.

Removing `TransferLog` entirely and only using `CustomLog` (because it allows log formatting whereas TransferLog doesn't) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If the expected condition isn't matching AND the format is wrong, the simplest explanation is that you have a  2nd `CustomLog` directive in your configuration.

Additionally, I would remove all of the ifmodules. You don't want this stuff being skipped if the modules aren't loaded, you want it to fail.

Comment: Good point on the `ifmodule` stuff. I will do that. I'll take a deeper look into a rogue `CustomLog`, you may be right,. This specific config is also using a separate SSL .conf file as well. You may have just swooshed a 3 pointer. ;)

Comment: Pretty close, but rather than a second CustomLog directive there was a TransferLog directive, which is very similar. So, rather than a 3 point swish, I'll give ya a "handoff to the dunk", so you still get the assist. Lol